# how to column and show in one from field admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, adminform

I an facing this problem the data is save in two different column. `date` and `time` for adding it is working but in edit how to combine these two field and show values in edit from.

for adding i am doing.

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data['start_datetime']));
$start_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($data['start_datetime']));
```

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement the `afterLoad` method in your module and do something like this:

```
public function afterLoad()
{
    $startDate = $this->getStartDate();
    $startTime = $this->getStartTime();
    $this->setData('start', $startDate.' '.$startTime);
    return parent::afterLoad();
}
```